# Drag-and-drop function to move a skier up and down a slope in D3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I want to create an interactive tutorial on web that can help students to understand the basic mechanics of skiing. The first thing I want to teach is the concept of conservation of mechanical energy. To do this, I want the students to interact with the skier. They should be able to move the skier up and down on the slope. And when they do this, the amount of potential energy should be calculated automatically. When the students drop the skier, the skier move/transit to the end of the slope where they can see the speed of the skier (ignoring applied forces such as air drag and friction).

When the students move the skier higher up on the slope, the slope should also follow the skier. I am coding the whole thing in D3.js. I don't know how I can do this at the moment, so I would appreciate if someone can guide me. This is my code thus far:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Skier!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-path.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-shape.v1.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

  <div>
      <input type="range" id="nAngle" name="degrees" min="0" max="90">
      <label for="degress">Angle</label>
  </div>


  </body>

  <script>

  // The values for my SVG canvas
  let w = 960,
      h = 500,
      middleW = w/2,
      middleH = h/2;

  let svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', w)
    .attr('height', h)

  // Creating a Group element so I can interact with all the elements of the skier
  let skier = svg.append('g')

 // Main body of the skier
   skier.append('rect')
    .attr('x', middleW)
    .attr('y', middleH)
    .attr('width', 30)
    .attr('height', 50)
    .attr('rx', 15)
    .attr('ry', 12)
    .attr('fill', 'green')
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("stroke-width", 5)    // set the stroke width  // set the line colour
    .attr("transform", "rotate(14, 50, 40)");

    // Pole
    skier.append('line')
        .attr("x1", middleW - 100)
        .attr("y1", middleH + 110)
        .attr("x2", middleW - 10)
        .attr("y2", middleH + 136)
        .attr('stroke', 'black')
        .style("stroke-width", 4);

      // Skis
    skier.append('line')
        .attr("x1", middleW - 90)
        .attr("y1", middleH + 170)
        .attr("x2", middleW + 5)
        .attr("y2", middleH + 190)
        .attr('stroke', 'black')
        .style("stroke-width", 4);

    // Path generator of beanie
    let arcBeanie = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(0)
      .outerRadius(12)
      .startAngle(0)
      .endAngle(Math.PI);

      skier.append('path')
      .attr('d', arcBeanie)
      .attr('fill', 'red')
      .attr('stroke', 'black')
      .style("stroke-width", 4)
      .attr("transform", "translate(436, 334) rotate(-90)");

      arcBeanie(); //

      // Path generator of face
      let arcFace = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(0)
      .outerRadius(12)
      .startAngle(0)
      .endAngle(Math.PI);


     skier.append('path')
        .attr('d', arcFace)
        .attr('fill', 'white')
        .attr('stroke', 'black')
        .style("stroke-width", 4)
        .attr("transform", "translate(436, 334) rotate(90)");

        arcFace(); //

      // Legs
      let arcLegs = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(22)
      .outerRadius(24)
      .startAngle(0)
      .endAngle(Math.PI - 1.5);


      skier.append('path')
        .attr('d', arcLegs)
        .attr('stroke', 'black')
        .style("stroke-width", 4)
        .attr("transform", "translate(415, 423) rotate(14)");

        arcLegs(); //

        // Arms
      let arcArms = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(0.25)
        .outerRadius(1)
        .startAngle(0)
        .endAngle(Math.PI - 1.4);


        skier.append('path')
        .attr('d', arcLegs)
        .attr('stroke', 'black')
        .style("stroke-width", 4)
        .attr("transform", "translate(450, 360) rotate(170)");

        arcLegs(); //


        d3.selectAll("g")
         .transition()
         .attr('transform', 'translate(300,0) rotate(20, 300, 0)')
          .attr('height', 600)
          .style('fill', 'teal')
         .duration(5000)

         d3.select("#nAngle").on("input", function() {
               update(+this.value);
             });

             // Initial starting angle of the skier
             update(0);

             // update the element
             function update(nAngle) {

               // adjust the text on the range slider
            //   d3.select("#nAngle-value").text(nAngle);
            //   d3.select("#nAngle").property("value", nAngle);

               // rotate the skier
               svg.select("g")
                 .attr("transform", "rotate("+nAngle+")");
             }

  </script>

</html>
```